# Session doesn't work in PHP

Tags: php, session, variables

I have two files, one file called Get_url.php, another file called Next.php. However, sessions are not working for me - session values are not remembered. What am I doing wrong?

This is my code for Get_url.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}

//connection
$con= mysql_connect("splasjcom.ipagemysql.com","splasj","Password") or die ("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("splasj") or die ("Could not select db");

$query = "SELECT id FROM articles WHERE url = '". curPageURL() . "'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 $idie = $row['id'];

 $Next = $idie +1;
 }
$queryy = "SELECT url FROM articles WHERE id = '$Next'";
$resultt = mysql_query($queryy);

while($roww = mysql_fetch_array($resultt)) {
 $idiee = $roww['url'];

 echo $idiee;
}

session_start();
$_SESSION['Get_url']=$idiee;
?>




</body>
</html>
```

This is my code for Next.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<?php include ('Get_url.php');
echo $idiee;
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['Get_url'];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is this having in it ?--> `$variable`

Comment: Did you set a value to `$variable`?

Comment: This sample code will never work. You may want to post your real code so we can see what is really happening.

Comment: yes, 
    $variable = "This is a varable";
And that works.

Comment: This would work. Show real code please.

Comment: @user3599598 please update your question with the code

Comment: where we cant see it in the code you've pasted ??

Comment: Maybe session handler wrong configured.

Comment: I updated the code above, now you can see everything.

Comment: If the session uses cookies at all, you want to call it before any output is sent to the browser. Look at http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Please remove hey.php and hello.php from the question, and the associated snippets of code. They will work (if `$variable` is set to something, at any rate), and are not representative of the problem at hand: that HTML output is forcing PHP to send headers, and thus `session_start` is effectively ignored.

Comment: What do you mean by "that HTML output is forcing PHP to send headers, "? I don't really understand you

Comment: Please use names (e.g. @halfer) to speak to someone specific here. See the first point in David's answer for more of an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues at play here. First of all you need to start your session before sending any output to the client. For example, your file should begin like so:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
```

If you do it the other way around (you send the `DOCTYPE` and `HTML` before the session is started) then PHP sends any pending HTTP headers followed by the content. By virtue of the way the HTTP protocol works, once any amount of content is sent, you cannot resend the headers. Thus a late session start (which needs to set a cookie header) will not work.

Your second issue is that you are calling a `session_start()` in Get_url.php, which is then `include()`ed in Next.php, which also has a `session_start()`. When you call that second `session_start()` it is overwriting the first session with a new session_id.

So in summary:

1. `session_start()` before outputting data to the user
2. only one `session_start()` at a time. If you must include another file that could potentially have a session_start() you may want to use something like this:

   ```
   $sid = session_id();
   if(empty($sid)) session_start();
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You first need to set a value to $variable

in Hey.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$variable = 'test';
$_SESSION['hey']=$variable;
?>
```

Comment: Do I have to change anything in Hello.php?
Cause when I try this, I get 'testest' as output...

Comment: No, the Hello.php file should render what is held in $_SESSION['hey']

Comment: I took hey.php and hello.php and after setting $variable to 'test' in hey.php,  I was able to see 'test' on hello.php